# Config .babelrc and out-dir/target directory parameters

Tags: javascript, config, babeljs

Is there a way to define out-dir & target directory in `.babelrc` file, instead of CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be, please see the documentation here: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/